# How to check ajax request status in selenium ChromeDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am writing a monitoring application for our website by Selenium ChromeDriver, I wrote a piece of code as follows:

```
public void Login()
{
    IWebDriver driver = null;
    try
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver(@".");
        driver.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LoginPath");
        var source = driver.PageSource;
        var username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
        var password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
        var login = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[id='Send']"));
        var credential = new Credentials();
        username.SendKeys(credential.UserName);
        password.SendKeys(credential.PassWord);

        login.click();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (driver != null)
        {
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that login method is called through `ajax` and I do not know how to get this request status since that it does not change the page URL?

Comment: if its your own page you could just set a javascript variable when you start your request and query that var from time to time. if its a foreign site then there must something change, like you're now logged in, a div on the page changed or whatever, so you can check the status of that.

Comment: i am new to selenium,could you show on code,how can i set javascript variable in selenium?

Comment: you have to set the javascript in your web app js code, not with selenium.  Then with selenium you can query javascript like this: `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;         
js.executeScript("return document.title");`